# Incremental Variance of Fixed Effects in a Mixed Effects Model Using R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model

I'm trying to determine the relative contribution of each variable, including the fixed effects, in explaining the overall model. The variance is provided to do this for the random effects, but I'm not sure how to do this for the fixed effects. Any suggestions for how to do this would be very much appreciated.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: time ~ agecat + sex + (1 | Resource) + (1 | Person)
   Data: subdata

REML criterion at convergence: 6699

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.4931 -0.5373 -0.1770  0.3340 13.4259 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Person   (Intercept)   7.68    2.771  
 Resource (Intercept)  18.73    4.327  
 Residual             638.44   25.267  
Number of obs: 722, groups:  Person, 42; Resource, 12

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)     53.5637     2.2043  24.299
agecat(0,11]    10.7435     8.8624   1.212
agecat(11,21]    0.8068     5.7625   0.140
agecat(65,80]    0.9927     2.1830   0.455
agecat(80,130]   1.6798     2.6869   0.625
sexM             6.9659     1.9073   3.652

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) a(0,11 a(11,2 a(65,8 a(80,1
agect(0,11] -0.118                            
agct(11,21] -0.164  0.037                     
agct(65,80] -0.357  0.095  0.150              
agc(80,130] -0.306  0.077  0.121  0.326       
sexM        -0.370 -0.017  0.023 -0.076 -0.017
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed effects don't have variance provided, because they are fixed, as they are point estimates, not random variables. You can [partition the explained variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131152/proportion-of-variance-in-dependent-variable-accounted-for-by-predictors-in-a-mi/131159#131159) by comparing the variances of the random effects $\sigma^2_\alpha, \sigma^2_\gamma, \dots$ to "total variance" understood as the sum of their variances and the residual variance $\sigma^2_\varepsilon$

$$ICC_\alpha = \frac{\sigma^2_\alpha}{\sigma^2_\alpha + \sigma^2_\gamma + ... + \sigma^2_\varepsilon}$$

but that's all. You would need to answer yourself what you mean by "relative contribution" because this is comparing apples to oranges, as fixed and random components play different roles in the model.